# Can I make one shape transparent on export?

Tags: inkscape

I have an SVG file with multiple things that should be exported individually with Inkscape. I have shapes in the background to set the size for each export. Would it be possible to make those shapes transparent while exporting?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if they are on a separate layer. First separate the parts onto different layers and then hide the layers that you don’t want to export.